# Obtaining p-value from bootstrapped Pearson's correlation using R

Tags: r, correlation, bootstrap, pearson-r

I am trying to carry out a bootstrapped Pearson's correlation using R software. I have 13 observations and originally I obtained: `Pearson r2=0.26; t = 1.96, df = 11, p-value = 0.08`. A reviewer suggested “... given the very small n for the correlation, bootstrapped p-values would be appropriate. Using bootstrapping with bias corrected acceleration and 5000 replicates in STATA you can obtain a lower p-value for the correlation between the variables `(p=.040; z = 2.05)`.”

```
Number of obs     =         13
                                                Replications      =      5,000
                                                Wald chi2(1)      =       4.21
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0403
                                                R-squared         =     0.2587
                                                Adj R-squared     =     0.1914
                                                Root MSE          =     0.2624

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
          oc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           s |   .6362245   .3102479     2.05   0.040     .0281498    1.244299
       _cons |   .1294286   .1652669     0.78   0.434    -.1944885    .4533458
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would need to obtain the non-bootstrapped and the bootstrapped p-values. I tried in R:

```
library(boot) 

bootCorTest <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i, ]
  res <-cor.test(d$x, d$y)$p.value
}

x<-c(0.8501, 0.7493, 0.7232, 0.6291, 0.5098, 0.5361, 0.3417, 0.323, 0.3147, 0.2511, 0.2327, 0.198, 0.1495)
y<-c(0.701, 0.324, 0.558, 0.917, 0.374, 0.469, 0.463, 0.785, 0.09, 0.023, 0.09, 0.045, 0.5351)
dat <- data.frame(x, y)

b <- boot(dat, bootCorTest, R = 5000)
b
b$t
```

I gather that I’m obtaining a list of p-values from each run in b$t, but I’m lost on how to obtain a single representative p-value from those, like Stata output shown above.

Comment: Your reviewer appears to be inviting statistical malpractice. Ordinarily, the conclusion following "given the very small $n$" ought to be that bootstrapping is *not* appropriate!  Regardless, you should be bootstrapping the *correlation,* not a p-value (as in `b <- boot(dat, function(x, i) with(x[i,], cor(x,y)), R=5e3)`), and then follow that up by applying `plot` and `boot.ci` to `b`. Then you *must* adjust all your p-values to account for the fact you are pursuing statistical significance by applying multiple tests -- and that's going to send your p-value back well above 0.05.

Comment: @Claudia I agree with all of  whuber's points. I'd add that when the assumptions hold the usual test of correlation works as it should at small samples and it is reasonably robust (in terms of correctness of significance level)  If you want a nonparametric test of Pearson correlation for small samples, a permutation test of the correlation would likely be a better option, but you can't avoid the multiple testing problem on these data - you already did a test.

Comment: In any case, if you were to have used the permutation test, it wouldn't have made a substantial difference to the p-value you got from the usual test.

Comment: Thanks so much @whuber and Glen_b for your insightful replay. Helps me a lot to discuss the issue with the reviewer.